# Am running the command setup:di:compile, I get this error:

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, php, setup-di-compile

php bin/magento setup:di:compile
Compilation was started.
Area configuration aggregation... 5/8 [========>-----]  62% 34 secs 348.0 MiB
In ClassReader.php line 43:

Class Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Image does not exist

In ClassReader.php line 36:

Class Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Image does not exist

setup:di:compile

Comment: If that class doesn't exist, you might have had an issue running composer before that.

Comment: Yes, I think @Claims is right, you need to run `composer update` first